# How to update multiple rows of a table from a query? And only update it if Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that needs to be updated from a query and check to update only if the records in the target table exist.

Source:

```
Id    Name
1     John Doe
2     Jane Doe
```

Target:

```
1     No Name 1
2     No Name 2
```

I wanted the name to be replaced based on their Id. How do I write a query to update the target based on the source and has a check if the id on target exists (not sure if this is necessary)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
update t
    set name = concat('No Name ', id)
    from target t join
         source s
         on s.id = t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do an `update` with `join`, if there is no connection a row won't be updated. Be aware that `id` in `source` should be `unique` in other case if there are two names for one id a random one will be chosen.

```
update t
set name = s.name
from target as t 
join source as s
    on s.id = t.id;
```